# Err imagepullbackoff on elasticsearch gke

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install elasticsearch on gke based on this [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html)
but it's giving me imagepullbackoff err

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       43s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned elastic-system/elastic-operator-0 to gke-cls-test-default-pool-fb827c76-vj15
  Warning  Failed          26s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.7.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.elastic.co/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed          26s                kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   SandboxChanged  26s                kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   BackOff         24s (x3 over 25s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.7.1"
  Warning  Failed          24s (x3 over 25s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling         10s (x2 over 41s)  kubelet            Pulling image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.7.1"
```

I had the same issue with pgadmin and PostgreSQL, I resolved them by removing the version at the end of the image name

```
example/test:1.1.2 -> example/test
```

and it worked but in this case it doesn't.
I have tried installing it on my local sys using minikube and it worked without any issue

```
#minikube
> kubectl get all -n elastic-system
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/elastic-operator-0   1/1     Running   1          86m

NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/elastic-webhook-server   ClusterIP   10.109.148.201   <none>        443/TCP   86m

NAME                                READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/elastic-operator   1/1     86m
```

Comment: Were you successful?

Comment: i managed to get it to work by creating a new cluster :/